# Geocoder Gem: Unable to reverse geocode certain Google Map results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

With the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), using the [advanced geocoding](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-geocoding) section I can't seem to get  it to work. I basically took every **Address Component Type** on the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON) and put it inside of the **Geocoder::Result block**:

```
geocoded_by :street_address  do |obj,results|
 if geo = results.first
  obj.route = geo.route
  obj.intersection = geo.intersection
  obj.political = geo.political
  obj.country = geo.country
  obj.administrative_area_level_1 = geo.administrative_area_level_1
  obj.administrative_area_level_2 = geo.administrative_area_level_2
  obj.administrative_area_level_3 = geo.administrative_area_level_3
  obj.colloquial_area = geo.colloquial_area
  obj.floor = geo.floor
  obj.room = geo.room
 end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

But I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in StoresController#create

undefined method `route' for #<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x6939150>
```

If I remove it this object it just goes to the next one, such as `intersection`.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the API documentation http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Google

```
 - (Object) address_components_of_type(type)

Get address components of a given type. Valid types are defined in Google's Geocoding API documentation and include (among others):

:street_number
:locality
:neighborhood
:route
:postal_code
```

So for the route example you need to call `geo.address_components_of_type(:route)`